# error in creating an update panel dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create an update panel dynamically for a purpose.
I want to dynamically create a checkbox and an update panel. update panel contains a label which is invisible and the trigger of update panel is the checkbox. what should happen is that when a user checks on checkbox, the label of updatepanel should be visible
This is my .aspx page-

```
      <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default8.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="LocalPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my .aspx.cs page through which I am trying to dynamically create update panel which refreshes at the checkedchanged event of a checkbox-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default8 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Label NewLabel;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =
                    new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createDiv.ID = "createDiv";
            CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();
            ch.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            ch.Text = "Add to compare";
            ch.ID = "ch";
            ch.AutoPostBack = true;
            ch.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(ch_CheckedChanged);
            createDiv.Controls.Add(ch);
            AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
            trigger.ControlID = ch.ID;
            trigger.EventName = "CheckedChanged";
            UpdatePanel up = new UpdatePanel();
            up.ID = "up";
            up.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.Visible = false;
            NewLabel.ID = "NewLabel";
            NewLabel.Text = "added";
            up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            createDiv.Controls.Add(up);
            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(up);
            LocalPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(createDiv);
        }
    }
    protected void ch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewLabel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

but when I am trying to execute this, this is the error which I get-`Control with ID 'up' being registered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl or RegisterPostBackControl must implement either INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, or IPostBackEventHandler.`
Please solve my problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to keep Page_Load in `!Ispostback`

Comment: it is not making any difference though I added !Ispostback

Comment: plz update your question how you added it and exact error you getting

Comment: you updated your Pageload code?

Comment: yes i did but thats not helping. if u want i can update !Ispostback here as well

Comment: The problem is that Label does not fire a postback event - it is not interactive. For something to be registered as a PostBackTrigger, it must somehow fire a Postback command - usually in response to some user input - which the UpdatePanel can then intercept. Or the control registered as the trigger must be able to contain controls which fire postback events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if:

1. You don't put the creation code in `if (!IsPostBack)`: the dynamic controls must be recreated on every postback
2. You add to the UpdatePanel a control that triggers a PostBack, like a Button (as mentioned by Webruster)
3. You register that control with `ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btn1)`, instead of registering the UpdatePanel itself